# Android XML error message

Tags: android, xml, xml-parsing

Everytime I open an XML layout file, the following error message displays:

`An internal error occurred during: "Check Android SDK".
java.util.ConcurrentModificationException`

The error message is easily dismiss-able, and my program still runs fine.  I have tried restarting Eclipse and my computer with no success.  The problem has not always been there, but I am not entirely sure when it started happening.  Any ideas or links are appreciated!

## Example XML file

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    tools:context="${packageName}.${activityClass}" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="@dimen/text_title_main"
    android:text="@string/app_name" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="@dimen/text_subtitle_main"
    android:text="@string/app_desc" />

</LinearLayout>
```

## Exact error message

[image: Example of popup]

Comment: No one will be able to help without more info. Post your xml code which is causing error

Comment: every XML layout file I have is causing the error, no matter how simple - not sure that would be helpful to post :(

Comment: In that case copy any one of the basic xml files.

Comment: or post a screenshot of the exact and complete error message

Comment: The entire error message is posted above, it appears as a popup.  I have updated with an example XML file

Comment: You can minimise the error window to avoid those annoying popups for the rest of the session. (This doesn't solve the root of the problem, I admit).

Answer (score 1):

Check your AndroidManifest.xml and see if the targeted SDK version matches the latest Android SDK Build tool you have downloaded.

Also check Eclipse under Window -> Preferences -> Android if the Platform is available and if the max API level matches.

Comment: This has helped me, at least for now.

Answer (score 0):

Well your code is fine and I'm not sure why there is an error. There is some thing you can try as the error asks you to check "android SDK"

In the menu bar

Select tools>-android>-SDK manager

and download the SDK build tools, SDK platform and Google API's for the target SDK version of your project.Make sure you have downloaded all the new updates, if any

if you are not sure which items you have to download , you can select all of them.(will take more time to download of course).no harm in trying

Restart the IDE

You can find more info here:
https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/adding-packages.html

Comment: Thanks for the tips, I will update this comment with my findings!

Comment: Unfortunately I was unable to find anything, and took it as my moment to migrate to Android Studio where I have had no problems

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and i resolve it by changing the target in the ADT plug-in

[image]

then chose the API that you are using in your application .

Answer (score 0):

Delete

> .metadata

folder that is in your workplace. Then import your project back. You will be good to go.

**Warning you will lose your workspace settings.**