# Eclipse and ADT Error

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I installed  `Eclipse and ADT plugin 23.0.4`, but sometimes when I click XML in my project，this problem may happens:

```
An internal error occurred during: "Check Android SDK".
    java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
```

I don't know why and I have already tried to delete the SDK files and download them again.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

This problem has already been discussed in detail [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25000313/android-xml-error-message).

You may have a problem with you Android SDK version. Check in you manifest and compare it to the SDKs you have installed. Start your Android SDK Manager and make sure you also have the tools installed, it is described in more detail [here](https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/adding-packages.html).

If none of that helps, you could always switch to [Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/tools/studio/index.html), which is now the "official Android IDE." Since I switched I have encounter fewer problems.